# C passing pointer to pointer in function

Tags: c, pointers

I am reading about pointer to pointer and now I think I know less than previous.
Passing double pointer is needed to change value of that pointer. But, if we have let's say pointer to some structure and we want to change the value of some of its members(fields), then we have to pass a simple pointer. Is the previous statement correct?

for example:

```
struct A* a;
void func(struct A* arg)
{
   arg->mem1 = 5;
}
```

and

```
struct *A a;
void func(struct A** arg)
{
   *arg = malloc(struct A);
   (*arg)->mem1 = 5;
   return;
}
```

I hope the above examples makes the problem clear.

Comment: We are very confused also.  *Please* show a code example!

Comment: Try compiling. `struct *A` is not valid.

Comment: It is rather simple: C is pass-by-value. If you want to modify an object in the caller, you have to pass a point to it. It that object is a point, the argument has to be a pointer to that pointer, of course.

Comment: `malloc(struct A);` is incorrect, try `malloc(sizeof(struct A));`

Comment: @chqrlie: maybe SO should require compiler warnings enabled and resolved for a C question.

Comment: @Olaf: that would help many programmers indeed. IMHO most warnings should be enabled by default.  Alas, from my experience here, newbies would be at a loss trying to fix the code to silence the warnings, and would still post the same code here with different headings: *Why the compiler gives warning XXXX?*

Comment: @chqrlie: That still would help us to get more precise diagnostic messags than "why does not code not run?" ...

Comment: @Olaf: yes indeed.  What about an automated downvote for questions without an MCVE, with `-Wall` warnings, with random indentation or chaotic style...

Comment: @chqrlie: Feel free to implement such a system. Although there is no general rule about that. Iff you solved that problem, you are a good candidate for a Nobel Price.

Comment: @Olaf: the Turing award is enticing, but it requires a lot more work and insight than this little hopeless challenge `;-)`.  I'm anal about style, correctness, coding rules etc. but not at all qualified for any such advanced academic work.

Comment: @Olaf: I realize you were thinking of the Nobel Peace Price... There is a long list of disputes one would need to solve: C style starters like TABs vs. spaces, K&R / java / GNU braces, `i++` vs. `++i`, `sizeof(x)` vs. `sizeof x`, `C` vs. `C++`, Mac vs. PC, Wndows vs. Linux, emacs vs. vim and a few more deeply rooted conflicts.

Comment: @chqrlie: To be honest: I actually was not. But the idea is quite appealing. At least it would pacify SO and many other forums. And then we care about the near and middle east. Well, at least people here don't kill each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You just need to pass a `pointer to struct` to change the fields inside the structure variable. This is because you are not changing the address but the value stored inside the structure var pointed to by the pointer.

If you need to allocate memory or change the address pointed to by the pointer and if that needs to be reflected in the calling function then your second function holds good.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right.
If you want pass a structure to function that have to change some of its fileds you need the pointer to the struct so the called function knows where the structure is in memory and can access/change the fileds:

```
void foo(struct a *pStruct)
{
    pStruct->field1 = 0;  //this field will be read modified.
}
```

Now if you want allocate a structure you have to pass the pointer:

```
struct Mystruct *ptr;
...
AllocMyStruct(&ptr);
ptr->field1 = 0;
```

`AllocMyStruct` can allocate memory so `ptr` will point to a freshly (dynamically) created struct:

```
AllocMyStruct(Mystruct **p)
{
    *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Mystruct));
    if (p==NULL)
        Error();
}
```

A pointer is a variable exactly as all others, so you can assign a value to it. Passing the address of a pointer is like to pass the address of an `int` or `float` to allow variable modification from inside a different function.